# Laravel exclude route in nested Middleware group

Tags: php, laravel, middleware

I have (schematically) the following situation:

```
MiddlewareGroup1{

    MiddlewareGroup2{

        Route::resource(...);
        ...
        Route::post('some-ajax-request', 'SomeController@action');

    }

    OtherNestedMiddlewareGroups{
        ...
    }

}
```

I have the problem that I want MiddlewareGroup2 to apply for the ajax route, but not MiddlewareGroup1. How can I make MiddlewareGroup1 not apply, but keep MiddlewareGroup2?

Comment: You don't want to create another MiddlewareGroup2 outside MiddlewareGroup1?

Comment: @rap-2-h rather not, It's for a big application with a lot of routes and I rather don't define multiple of the same groups to keep a good structured overview in the routes file, if that makes sense

Comment: Ok I understand, but IMO it *makes more sense* to have MiddlewareGroup2 out of MiddlewareGroup1 if it does not apply. Anyway, it's just an opinion!

Comment: @rap-2-h middlewaregroup1 makes sure that all user requests gets logged and saved in the db. Middleware 2 is admin routes. I want ajax requests to not be logged as a "user called route" in the db, but the request can only be fired by an admin user, that's kinda the situation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess there is not built in solution here. You can put this route outside `MiddlewareGroup1` or you could check current request url in `MiddlewareGroup1`, like:

```
....
if ($request->is('some-ajax-request')) {
    return $next($request);
}
....
```

This will skip `MiddlewareGroup1` middleware for defined URL(s).

If you have many similar ajax routes, you could use similar URLs for them ('ajax-add-stuff', 'ajax-do-some-stuff' etc) and check them like this:

```
if ($request->is('ajax*')) { .... }
```

Comment: Good answer, thanks! As an addition, to exclude more routes I'll define an array with excluded routes in the middleware and foreach+ifelse them to check if it's valid.